# Php last login time and current login time difference... Right or wrong?

Tags: php, datetime

My code is there:

[How to show last login time ( year,month,week,day,time,sec).. i tried but Wrong output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547982/how-to-show-last-login-time-year-month-week-day-time-sec-i-tried-but-wrong)

Last login is: 2012-05-11 10:16:51 Current Time is: 2012-05-11 10:35:51

```
$diff_seconds = strtotime($current_time) - strtotime($lastLoginTime);
```

is this right ans of `$diff_seconds -1336724211`

Answer (score 1):

The following code gives me `1140`:

```
<?php echo strtotime('2012-05-11 10:35:51') - strtotime('2012-05-11 10:16:51');  ?>
```

There probably is an error elsewhere in your code that you're not showing us.

Comment: my question is there 


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547982/how-to-show-last-login-time-year-month-week-day-time-sec-i-tried-but-wrong

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce that. I did

```
$time1 = '2012-05-11 10:16:51';
$time2 = '2012-05-11 10:35:51';

echo strtotime($time1) - strtotime($time2);
echo '<br>';
echo strtotime($time2) - strtotime($time1);
```

And I got

-1140

1140

Looks legit. Please show your code. Maybe you did not have a string and it did some weird calculation with your year digits?

Comment: My code is there 



http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547982/how-to-show-last-login-time-year-month-week-day-time-sec-i-tried-but-wrong

Comment: @nareshkumar - You can't do decent date calculations dividing by number of seconds. You'll ignore DST, leap seconds, leap years... There're many bultin functions to do the job for you.

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to try **date_diff** (PHP 5 >= 5.3.0) as an option?

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

```
<?php
$datetime1 = date_create('2012-05-11 10:16:51');
$datetime2 = date_create('2012-05-11 10:35:51');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%s seconds');
?>
```